# is there a difference between 電視上vs電視裡?

Tags: grammar

兩個說法對吧？有沒有差別？
I believe we can add both after the word TV in chinese but there must be a slight difference in usage or meaning  no? like shang would be more the object and li may be referring to the program. thx in adavnce for your help

Comment: If you want to refer the object, we usually say "电视机上/里面", as "电视" often means "program" nowadays.

Comment: @Shaw I think its the same in English, "watching television" can refer to either the device itself or the contents therein, one might even "watch TV" on their computer

Answer (score 3):

Depends how you look at it but you could equate them to the following English:

- 電視上 = on the tv
- 電視裡 = in the (tv) show

In the second one I'm inclined to treat 電視 as a noun meaning "TV show," whereas in the first one it's more likely to just be "TV" on its own.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically:

電視(螢幕)上(的影象) --> (images) on the tv (screen)

電視(節目)裡(的內容) --> (content) in the tv (program)

In practice, images on the screen compile the content; the contents in tv programs are showed through images, therefore, 電視上 and 電視裡 are almost interchangeable. Both 電視上的節目 and 電視裡的節目 are valid

Answer (score 0):

都正确，日常表达中都会用，没任何差别，一般都指电视（剧情）里的内容。

但如果说是说方位，那么有一点点差别：

- “电视上”：应该是物体表面之上（on）
- “电视里”：应该是物体内部（in）